# Visual Studio 2013 hangs on startup w splash screen

Tags: visual-studio, splash-screen

I have installed VS 2013 Ultimate(and had community) but when it run it just shows a white rectangle, a splash screen I guess. task manager shows that it stay at 15K mb, no activity

[image: splash screen]

I have tried many solution that apparently worked for others:

-Devenv /ResetSkipPkgs

-Devenv /SafeMode

-sfc /scannow

-DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

-I do not have HTTP Debugger, FastPictureViewer, preview edition of IE or Canon Hack Development Kit

The only thing that can start Visual Studio running it from a commant prompt with "devenv /ResetSettings". However the next time I start it (without resetsettings) I get presented with the same white rectangle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed partially the problem, I'm now able to start Visual Studio 2013 with no launch parameter. What I did is start VS with `devent /ResetSettings` then I went to `Tools` -> `Import and Export Settings Wizard` -> `Reset all settings` but now I cannot create project without an error message, more info [here](https://superuser.com/questions/938556/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-custommarshalers)